# How do I output files for post_id?

Tags: python, nsregularexpression

How do I output files 69_0.jpg , 69_1.jpg, 69_2.jpg for post_id?

#folder photo: 69_0.jpg, 69_1.jpg, 69_2.jpg, 970.jpg

```
def jpg():
    post_id =  69
    text = "Hello World"

    pics = glob.glob(f'photo//*.jpg')
    
            
    mylist = []
    for pi in pics:
            mylist.append(pi)
            photo = ','.join(mylist)

    print(photo, text)

jpg()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: I agree that you should look at the links there^ but just in case I can help, I think the `photo = ','.join(imylist)` is likely the source of your problem. 

You probably only want to do that once after you've looped through the pics, but right now it's happening every loop

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you need to do? What is the problem with the code you have here? What does it do as it is, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: How to extract files from a folder for post_id?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. I don't understand what this `post_id` means - you don't use it in code. Maybe you menas `if post_id in pi: ...` or `if pi.startswith(post_id): ...` or you should use `glob.glob(f'photo//{post_id}*.jpg')` to use `photo//69*.jpg`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter filenames and get only names which start with `69` (`post_id`) then you can use path `photo/69*.jpg` without `for`-loop.

```
mylist = glob.glob(f'photo/{post_id}*.jpg')
```

If you have names with `69` between other words then you can use second `*` before `{post_id}`

```
mylist = glob.glob(f'photo/*{post_id}*.jpg')
```

---

But `glob()` gives list with `photo/` in every path and you will have to remove it from every element if you want only filenames.

```
mylist = [x.rename('photo/', '') for x in mylist]
```